# Compile errors after upgrading from Xcode 6 Beta 6 to Xcode 6.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a problem since I upgraded from Xcode 6 Beta 6 to Xcode 6.0.1.

With Xcode 6.0.1, I have 62 errors but none with the beta.

Example:

```
    balloonro.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (circleOfRadius: balloonro.size.width/2)
    balloonro.physicsBody.dynamic = true
    balloonro.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = balloonCategory | pinkCategory
    balloonro.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = flechetteCategory
    balloonro.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = balloonCategory
    balloonro.physicsBody.mass = 1
    balloonro.physicsBody.restitution = 1
    balloonro.physicsBody.allowsRotation = true
```

On all lines, Xcode 6.0.1 said:

> 'SKPhysicsBody?' does not have a member named 'restitution/mass/dynamic/etc.'

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SKPhysicsBody?` is optional value. You have to unwrap it or use optional chaining. For exmaple,

```
balloonro.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
```

Comment: Thank you I will try in few hours. Why is it working on beta?

Comment: A lot of SDK classes changed. A lot of non-optionals become optionals. I had my project full of errors as well after upgrade.